# how to build function to detect negation in sentiment analysis

Tags: python, string, nlp, negation

I want to build negation detection for Malay text, it is to tackle a problem like 'not beautiful' detected as a positive word. so here is some coding that I modified but the result is not something that I wanted it to be.

The result is

```
text= "is not good, danish died,"
se=negate(self=None,text=text)
print(se)
['is', 'not', 'not_good', 'not_danish', 'not_died']

I wanted it to be
['is', 'not', 'not_good', 'danish', 'died']
```

only word after "not" is changed to "not_" form.
this is the function that I use, any advice to change and add in order to get the result as i wanted?

```
def negate(self,text):

    negation = False
    result = []
    words = text.split()

    for word in words:
        # stripped = word.strip(delchars)
        stripped = word.strip(delims).lower()
        negated = "not_" + stripped if negation else stripped
        result.append(negated)

        if any(neg in word for neg in ["not", "n't", "no"]):
            negation = not negation

    return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly you only want the word immediately following "not" or "n't" or "no" to be negated.

So after you add the negated word to the result, set negation to false, and after a "not", set negation to true